# Epson XP-420 will not print black or blue

Tags: multi-function-printer

My Epson 420 will only print yellow and blue, what can I do?

I have tried:

1. Replaced all of the cartridges
2. Cleaned the heads
3. Alignment
4. Nozzle check

....all to no avail!! Help!!!!